# How to add z-index to geojson layers in leaflet maps?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I need to set z-index to my geosjson layers created in leaflet that is bar chart and a choropleth. I tried doing mymap.addLayer(ChinaBarChart).setZIndex(2) but it doesnt work at all. Is there any other alternative ways to set the z-index of the layers? The setZIndex method was based on a leaflet method, if you do know of a way to making it work do let me know?

```
// HTML code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Map Testing</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
        <!-- Cdn for jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Cdn for Barcharts -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-dvf/0.3.1/leaflet-dvf.markers.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-d4jm/DxK0vxzigVql4lmwFikmXIlItcko9Me2md/mwI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-motion.js"></script>
        <!-- Event handling of checking of checkboxes -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // Hides the piechart at the beginning
                if($(".leaflet-piechart-icon")){
                    $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").hide();
                }
                // Hides the piechart legend at the beginning
                if($(".legend")){
                    $(".legend").hide();
                }
                // Hides the stringlines at the beginning
                if($(1 == 1)){
                    mymap.removeLayer(polyline);
                }
                // Hides the barchart at the beginning
                if($(1 == 1)){
                    mymap.removeLayer(IndiaBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(ChinaBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(MalaysiaBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(UaeBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(TaiwanBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(IndonesiaBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(TurkeyBarChart);
                }
                // Hides the choropleth at the beginning
                if($(1 == 1)){
                    mymap.removeLayer(ChinaArea);
                }
                // Shows or hides layers when checkbox is checked or unchecked
                $('input[id="pie-charts"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").show(500);
                        $(".legend").show(500);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").hide(500);
                        $(".legend").hide(500);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="bar-charts"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        mymap.addLayer(IndiaBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(ChinaBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(MalaysiaBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(UaeBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(TaiwanBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(IndonesiaBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(TurkeyBarChart);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        mymap.removeLayer(IndiaBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(ChinaBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(MalaysiaBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(UaeBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(TaiwanBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(IndonesiaBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(TurkeyBarChart);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="choropleth"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        mymap.addLayer(ChinaArea);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        mymap.removeLayer(ChinaArea);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="string-lines"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        mymap.addLayer(polyline);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        mymap.removeLayer(polyline);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- Access style.css file in the same folder -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div class="line line-1"></div>
                    <div class="line line-2"></div>
                    <div class="line line-3"></div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="pie-charts"> Pie Charts
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="bar-charts"> Bar Charts
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="choropleth"> Choropleth
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="string-lines"> String Lines
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
        <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-choropleth.js"></script>
        </div>
        <script src="http://sashakavun.github.io/leaflet-canvasicon/leaflet-canvasicon.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet-piechart.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-barchart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```